# How to retrieve facebook inbox using php sdk

Tags: php, facebook

Ok so here is the thing, I have been searching all over facebook docs and Googling all day long without any functional result.

My goal is to create an application that lets me retrieve and send facebook messages, just like a facebook messenger application, I have already hosted my semi functional code in heroku and been able to ask for permissions to read data from the user that logs into the app.

I can retrieve some of the information of the user that logs in (in this case my own account) using the facebook php sdk and the following lines of code:

```
//the facebook object is created
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => AppInfo::appID(),
 'secret' => AppInfo::appSecret(),
 'sharedSession' => true,
 'trustForwarded' => true,
 ));

 $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
 if ($user_id) {
 try {
   // Fetch the viewer's basic information
    $basic = $facebook->api('/me');
 } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
     // If the call fails we check if we still have a user. The user will be
     // cleared if the error is because of an invalid accesstoken
if (!$facebook->getUser()) {
  header('Location: '. AppInfo::getUrl($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
  exit();
     }
  }

   // This fetches some things that you like . 'limit=*" only returns * values.
  // To see the format of the data you are retrieving, use the "Graph API
   // Explorer" which is at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/
   $likes = idx($facebook->api('/me/likes?limit=4'), 'data', array());

  // This fetches 4 of your friends.
   $friends = idx($facebook->api('/me/friends?limit=4'), 'data', array());

   // And this returns 16 of your photos.
   $photos = idx($facebook->api('/me/photos?limit=16'), 'data', array());
```

Up until here I have three arrays "likes" "friends" and "photos" which I can easily echo by putting them inside a foreach cycle and using the idx() method (which I'm not sure what it's function is) like this:

```
  <section id="samples" class="clearfix">
  <h1>Examples of the Facebook Graph API</h1>

  <div class="list">
    <h3>A few of your friends</h3>
    <ul class="friends">
      <?php
        foreach ($friends as $friend) {
          // Extract the pieces of info we need from the requests above
          $id = idx($friend, 'id');
          $name = idx($friend, 'name');
      ?>
      <li>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/<?php echo he($id); ?>" target="_top">
          <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo he($id) ?>/picture?type=square" alt="<?php echo he($name); ?>">
          <?php echo he($name); ?>
        </a>
      </li>
```

The problem comes when I try to get all the messages in the inbox of the user (note that I DO have permission to get them), I use the following code to ask for them:

```
 $messages = $facebook->api('/me/inbox');
```

but it seems to return a lot of nested arrays and I cannot get any usable data out of it.
I have been trying with the foreach method just like with the others but the only thing that it echoes is "Array" every time.

Just now I have use the var_dump method over the $messages object and it shows the nested hierarchy of arrays, but still, I'm not sure how to get the info from there, here is a bit of that echoed string:

```
array(25) { [0]=> array(6) { ["id"]=> string(13) "[idnumbersIcantshow]" ["to"]=> array(1) { ["data"]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(12) "MyName" ["id"]=> string(10) "idnumbersIcantshow" } [1]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(9) "TheOtherPersonName" ["id"]=> string(10) "idnumbersIcantshow" } } } ["updated_time"]=> string(24) "2012-12-31T05:35:28+0000" ["unread"]=> int(0) ["unseen"]=> bool(false) ["comments"]=> array(2) { ["data"]=> array(25) { [0]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(16) "idnumbersIcantshow" ["from"]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(9) "TheOtherPersonName" ["id"]=> string(10) "idnumbersIcantshow" } ["message"]=> string(24) "Message That Was Sent That I wont show" ["created_time"]=> string(24) "2012-10-13T04:11:24+0000" } [1]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(16) "idnumbersIcantshow" ["from"]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(9) "TheOtherPersonName" ["id"]=> string(10) "idnumbersIcantshow" } ["message"]=> string(53) "Another Message Sent which I wont show either" ["created_time"]=> string(24) "2012-10-13T04:11:41+0000" } [2]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(16) "idnumbersIcantshow" ["from"]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(12) "MyName" ["id"]=> string(10) "idnumbersIcantshow" } ["message"]=> string(45) "More private bla bla bla" ["created_time"]=> string(24) "2012-10-13T04:12:24+0000" } [3]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(16) .... and it keeps going with all my conversations
```

How can I get this info into beautifully simple variables like these:

```
&conversationParticipantsArray
$messagesArray
  {
   $from
   &message
  }
```

I want to retrieve mainly that data. This is my not so useful foreach code:

```
foreach($messages as $message)
  {
?>
  <div id="messages">

<?php echo var_dump($message);?>

  </div>
```

Hope you can help me and thanks.

Comment: At last I was able to retrieve all my messages from facebook, I know that there is not something more annoying than looking at a question without a useful answer so here is how I did it:

Comment: "$messages = $facebook->api('/me/inbox');"                      $threads=idx($messages,"data");
    $toUsers=idx($threads[0],"to");
    $idThread=idx($threads[0],"id");
    $msgsData=idx($threads[0],"comments");
    $msgs=idx($msgsData,"data");
    $users=idx($toUsers,"data");
    foreach($users as $user){echo "Participants: ".idx($user,"name")."</br>";
    }
    foreach($msgs as $msg)
    {
      $msgFrom=idx($msg,"from");
      echo "From: ".idx($msgFrom,"name")."</br>";
      echo "Message: ".idx($msg,"message")."</br>";
    }

Comment: The only problem I had was that I couldn't understand how the arrays were nested, also some of the arrays have to be retrieved first by using the "data" key so after adding it to the code and looking how the data was nested using var_dump($messages) everything went great. Hope this helps you, and if you have any comment or question please let me know.

Comment: you'd better post your answer as an answer. Because it is the purpose of answers, and because it will be more readable.